# How to display an image in footwear.php page being retrieved by getImage.php page?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm new to php and am having trouble retrieving an image for display in a page. The image path is stored in a mysqli database under the column image. My code is listed below. Any help would be appreciated.

**footwear.php**

```
<img class="product-item_image" src="getImage.php?id=1" alt="Product">
```

**getImage.php**

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname","3307");
$sql = "SELECT image FROM dbname.product_catalog WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$image = $row['image'];
$image_src = $image;
mysqli_close($link);
echo "<img src='$image' >";
?>
```

when I navigate to getImage.php?id=1 the image is successfully displaying. However, when I'm viewing footwear.php the image is broken. I know there is something fundamentally wrong with my code, but I don't know what the next step is to get this to function as I'm intending.

Note, the Mysql database column  holds the value "amour-03-bsat.jpg", but I'm unsure of how to get this value into footwear.php. I'm open to any other method of getting my image to display as well.

Thanks!

Comment: `getImage.php` should be spaffing out the [binary (base64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) encoded image data *not* an HTML image tag if you want to take that approach.

Comment: what does your rendered path display?

Comment: Looks like you'll be getting this `<img class="product-item_image" src="<img src='[ImgPath]' >" alt="Product">` on your page. Have you tried just echoing the `$image` variable?

Comment: I tried echoing $image and it returns the correct path (amour-03-bsat.jpg) viewing getImage.php?id=1, which is great. However, the image still isn't displaying in footwear.php

Do I need to echo this back to footwear.php somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

**footwear.php**

```
<?php
 require_once('getImage.php');
 $image = imagePath($id=1);
 <img class="product-item_image" src="$image" alt="Product">
?>
```

**getImage.php**

```
<?php
 function imagePath($id) {
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname","3307");
  $sql = "SELECT image FROM dbname.product_catalog WHERE id='$id'";
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  $image = $row['image'];
  mysqli_close($link);
  return $image;
 }
?>
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Sathiskumar,

Thank you for the example. footwear.php is a page which will have many thumbnails (a catalog). How would I modify this if there are multiple images I need to display on the page? Each item has its own unique id.

For instance, in my example I have 

<img class="product-item_image" src="getImage.php?id=1" alt="Product">

But there will also be 

<img class="product-item_image" src="getImage.php?id=2" alt="Product">

a little further down on the page.

Comment: @Mackeo Is my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, I had to toy with it a little bit, but it ended up doing exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks!